# how can I distinct a queryset but also select what is needed in different field? django

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, distinct, django-queryset

A bit hard to explain within few lines but what I am trying to get from the queryset is to remove all duplicated names but also return a boolean field.
I think it'll be easier to show examples.

```
Model.order_by('-selected', 'name').distinct('selected', 'name')
```

this would give me queryset and what's inside would be something like for my output..

```
[
  {
    "selected": true,
    "id": 163,
    "name": "11111111"
  },
  {
    "selected": true,
    "id": 178,
    "name": "22222222222"
  },
  {
    "selected": false,
    "id": 152,
    "name": "152-JE"
  },
  {
    "selected": false,
    "id": 163,
    "name": "11111111"
  },
  {
    "selected": false,
    "id": 178,
    "name": "22222222222"
  },
  {
    "selected": false,
    "id": 213,
    "name": "mingzi"
  }
]
```

What I want for my output is to `distinct` all duplicated names and show `selected: True` (if there is one. If there is no True, show the one that's with `False` but now it would show both.  I wanted to do `distinct('name')`, I don't have to use `order_by` but I thought by doing it, it would make the one with `True` on top and then distinct those at bottom.  I cannot only do `order_by('select')` then `distinct('name')` since what's in order_by needs to be in distinct.

Can someone please give me a hand?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The description is a bit confusing but try the following (Django < 1.10).

First get all the models which have selected True:

```
true_models = Model.objects.filter(selected=True).distinct('name').values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Then get all the models which are true or false. But if there is a name which is selected true and false only keep the one which is true.

```
Model.objects.exclude(selected=False, id__name=true_models).order_by('name').distinct('name')
```

You may want to add an extra filter by another condition. If this is the case add the filter in both queries.

Comment: I would get such error though

`Unsupported lookup 'name' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.`

name is actually a `ForeignKey` field.  in the model though

Comment: Ok so update your post with the field which must be unique from the foreignKey model. Then I can update mine with the corrections. But the logic would be the same you just need to change name for the actual field with: "name__FIELD".